# Real-valued polynomials on matrix groups.

Tags: polynomials, lie-groups, matrix-calculus

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional, real Banach space. We say $p:V\to\mathbb R$ is a polynomial if it is smooth with $m^{\mathrm{th}}$ derivative identically zero: $\nabla^m p\equiv 0$.

Let $G\hookrightarrow M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ be a compact, real matrix group, embedded in some matrix algebra. We say that $p:G\to\mathbb R$ is a polynomial if $p$ is the restriction of some polynomial, $q:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$, to $G$.

---

My question: is this definition of polynomials on $G$ independent of the embedding of $G$ into some matrix algebra? E.g., if we instead embed $G\hookrightarrow M_{(n+1)\times(n+1)}(\mathbb R)$, do we get the same space of 'polynomials on $G$'?

Comment: Isn't that definition equivalent to "$p\circ \lambda_i$ is a polynomial for each $i$" where $\lambda_i:\mathbb{R}\to V$ is the embedding onto $i$-th coordinate?

Comment: @juanarroyo Then yes, you are misunderstanding something. There are of course always non-zero polynomials, for example elements of the dual space are polynomials of degree $m\leq 1$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. A function is polynomial iff its $m$-the derivative is constant zero for some $m$ and the least such $m$ will be the degree+1 of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The question basically boils down to whether two continuous homomorphisms $G\to GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ can differ by something non-polynomial. it turns out that this is not the case.

First note that "polynomial in $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$" is the same as "polynomial in $z$ and $\overline{z}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}^n$" so that I will directly look at the complex case.

I claim:

> A continuous function $f: G\to\mathbb{C}$ is polynomial iff it is a polynomial in the entries $\phi_k(\cdot)_{ij}$ of the irreducible representations $\rho_k: G\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Since the set of those representations is only determined by $G$, this is no longer dependent on any particular embedding. Instead we now look at *all* continuous homomorphisms $\rho: G\to U(n)$ at the same time.

Now for the proof.

We start with classical representation theory: A compact group has an invariant Haar-probability-measure so that we can average many things over $G$. For example there is always a $G$-invariant scalar product $\langle,\rangle$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ by averaging rotated copies of the euclidean scalar product $\langle,\rangle_2$:
$$\langle x,y\rangle := \int_G \langle gx,gy\rangle_2 dg$$

By finding an orthonormal basis for this invariant scalar product, we find that all compact groups are conjugated to subgroups of $U(n)$.

The set of polynomial functions doesn't change under conjugation with any fixed matrix. That means: We can replace $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ by $U(n)$ for our purposes.

What this gives us is Maschke's theorem: Now that we have unitary matrices, we can decompose $\mathbb{C}^n$ into a orthogonal, direct sum of $G$-invariant subspaces. Those continuous homomorphisms $\rho: G\to U(n)$ that cannot be decomposed in this way any further are called *irreducible* representations of $G$. We have just shown: *Every* continuous, finite-dimensional, complex representation of $G$ decomposes as a direct sum of irreducibles.

One can show more: These decompositions are actually unique up to conjugation.

Now observe that we can build now representations out of old ones: If $G\to Gl(V)$ is a representation on some complex vector space $V$, $G$ also acts on the dual space $V^\ast$, on direct sums $V^{\oplus n}$, tensor powers $V^{\otimes n}$ and any combination thereof.

One can also prove the following theorem: If $\psi: G\to Gl(V)$ is any fixed *injective* representation, then *all* irreducible representations occur as summands of somewhere in the induced representations $V^{\otimes n}\otimes (V^\ast)^{\otimes m}$.

This is important for our problem because polynomial functions $V\to\mathbb{C}$ are exactly the same as elements of the symmetric algebra $Sym(V^\ast) = \mathbb{C} \oplus V^\ast \oplus (V^\ast)^{\otimes 2} \oplus (V^\ast)^{\otimes 3}\oplus\cdots$ and polynomial functions in $\overline{z}$ are exactly the same as the symmetric algebra $Sym(V)$.

And that's basically it: You start with your embedding $\psi: G\to U_n(\mathbb{C})$. The dual representation is given by the $\psi^\ast: G\to U_n(\mathbb{C}), g\mapsto \overline{\psi(g)}$. Now you take all possible direct sums of all possible tensor products of $\psi$ and $\psi^\ast$. The coefficients of these matrices are all the possible polynomial functions evaluated at $\psi(g)$ and $\overline{\psi(g)}$. On the other hand these matrices are also conjugated to all possible representations of $G$ and since conjugation preserves the set of polynomial functions, this proves the theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Johannes - this looks very promising. I still haven't completely understood it (probably due to my poor knowledge of rep. theory). In particular, could you please expand on the paragraph "If $\phi:G\to Gl(V)$ is any fixed injective representation..."? What do you mean by irreducible reps "occuring as  summands of somewhere in the induced representations"?

Comment: By "representation" I just mean "group homomorphism $G\to GL(V)$" for some vector space $V$. And in this case all vector spaces are finite-dimensional and every representation is a continuous mapping for the topology of $G$ and the standard topology on $GL(V)\subseteq\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. By "summands" I mean the orthogonal decomposition into G-invariant subspaces. For every G-invariant subspace $X\leq Y$ you get another representation $G\to GL(X)$ by restricting the action of $g$ from all of $Y$ to $X$. Decompose $Y=X_1\oplus...\oplus X_k$ in this way until you cannot decompose any further

Comment: ... and what you get are the "irreducible summands" of $Y$. One also calls the associated homomorphisms $\rho_j: G\to GL(X_j)$ "irreducible representation" in this case.